# Change behavior of buttons inside an arraylist

Tags: button, android-arrayadapter, imagebutton

I have a custom arrayadapter based off of [this](https://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/listview-item-with-button/) code, except it instead has a button and an imagebutton side by side rather than the edit text boxes. I also have the rows added at the beginning at the activity with each button's text being changed to distinguish it for the user. Each button and imagebutton need to do something different, which is where my problem is. All of the buttons execute the same method, and all of the imagebuttons execute another method. I need each button and each imagebutton to either execute a separate method or send data when clicked to indicate which button/imagebutton was pressed.

This is an example of how the layout looks:

### [Button 1][imagebutton 1]

### [Button 2][imagebutton 2]

### [Button 3][imagebutton 3]

### [Button 4][imagebutton 4]

### [Button 5][imagebutton 5]

### [Button 6][imagebutton 6]

### [Button 7][imagebutton 7]

Button 1 should either execute a different method from buttons 2-7 or indicate that it was the button pressed, with buttons 2-7 also behaving this way. The imagebuttons should also behave like this.

If anything's unclear let me know, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `onClickListener` for each button in the `getView` method of the adapter.

Comment: The number of buttons will be variable, there could be 7 or 2 or 24 rows of buttons. Would I still be able to use this technique even though they are variable?

Comment: @user2419281 in the `Adapter`'s `getView` you set behaviour of a single row, it does not matter how many of them you want to be